# WordPress get_post_galleries_images( $post->ID ) is only showing thumbnail images

Tags: wordpress

WordPress get_post_galleries_images( $post->ID ) is only showing thumbnail images. The image uploaded from editor to gallery is re-sized to different sizes and the function get_post_galleries_images( $post->ID ) is showing the 150x150 size image. How can I show the full sized uploaded image. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a duplicate of [get_post_gallery_images returns thumbs . I want full size](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120544/get-post-gallery-images-returns-thumbs-i-want-full-size)

> You need to add size="full" attribute to the gallery shortcode in the
>   post content like
>
> `[gallery ids="836,830,829" size="full"]`